# Quickly change host for bluetooth keyboard

Tags: applications, keyboard, bluetooth

A while ago I stumbled upon an app that made it possible to change the device that a Bluetooth keyboard is connected to. This would allow me to quickly switch the keyboard between being connected to the iPad, or iMac or MacBook. Unfortunately, I forgot the name of this utility.

Does anyone know of a utility that would allow me to do this? In my case I'd want to switch between iPad and a MacBook.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [type2phone](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/type2phone/id472717129?mt=12&ign-mpt=uo=4)? It allows you to use the keyboard of your Mac on your iDevice...

Comment: nope not really. :/